# Python Serial not reading on one line

Tags: python, line, pyserial

I'm trying to read serial data from an EAS decoder and log it into a text file with python. 
When I use a commercial serial logger this is what I get:

```
1A Broadcast station or cable system has issued a Tornado Warning for all of 
 Iowa beginning at 7:54 pm and ending at 8:54 pm (MEWDOG)
```

The output when I run the file is this (I didn't include the entire output, but you get the idea):

image of output

[image]

This is my code below. It only writes the first character to the text file, but I need it to be all on one line on the text file output.

```
import serial
import os
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM2'
ser.open()
def write_txt(EAS):
    import os.path
    fileName = "eas.txt"
    pathOfTxt = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(fileName))
    with open(pathOfTxt, 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(EAS)+'\n')
    return()

while True:
    message = ser.read()
    write_txt(message)
    print(message)
```

Thanks!

Comment: change `with open(pathOfTxt, 'w') as f:` to `with open(pathOfTxt, 'w+') as f:`

Comment: That didn't work... I changed my code to what @eyllanesc said, and it still just prints the first character to the text file. I'm not getting the serial text received to be on one line. Thanks!

Comment: try with this: `import serial
import os

import os.path

fileName = "eas.txt"
pathOfTxt = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(fileName))

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM2'
ser.open()

with open(pathOfTxt, 'w+') as f:    
    while True:
        message = ser.read()
        f.write(str(message))
        print(message)`

Comment: or this: `import serial
import os

import os.path

fileName = "eas.txt"
pathOfTxt = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(fileName))

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.port = 'COM2'
ser.open()

with open(pathOfTxt, 'w') as f:    
    while ser.is_open:
        message = ser.readall()
        f.write(str(message))
        print(message)`

Answer (score 0):

```
f.write(str(EAS)+'\n')
```

This is the problem. You're appending a newline after EAS. Change it to:

```
f.write(str(EAS))
```